# Instalar Pivoting (pivot_longer() and pivot_wider()) de tidyr en R

Tags: base-de-datos, r, filtro, pivot

¿Qué tal?

Hace unos meses Wickham anunció que ya no se usaría `spread` ni `gather` de la librería de Tidyverse y que en su lugar entraría `pivot_longer()` y `pivot_wider()`.

Si quiero probar estas nuevas funciones, necesito instalar la versión de desarrollo de `tidyr` de la siguiente manera:

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")
```

Pero no logro hacerlo, ocupo cualquiera de las nuevas funciones y no las identifica. Instalé al menos 8 paquetes de una lista que apareció cuando corres el comando anterior, pero hay uno en particular (`vctrs`) que siempre me manda un error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionar eso?

A la hora de cargar la librería `tidyverse`, obtengo estos resultados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y a pesar de qué la versión de `tidyr` ya es la 0.8.3.9000, sigue sin encontrar las nuevas funciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realicé los pasos que me recomendó `pmoracho` y sigo sin obtener las funciones que busco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En primer lugar `gather()` y `spread()` no parece que vayan a ser reemplazadas, según palabras de Hadley:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo siguiente es tratar de instalar la versión de desarrollo de `tidyr` ya que estás funciones no se han incorporado a la rama estable del proyecto aún. Esto parece que no es una tarea sencilla, intuyo sobretodo, en un entorno Windows. Antes que nadas necesitarás [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) para poder compilar todo el código C++ de las versiones de desarrollo ya que no dispones de versiones precompiladas para Windows. Una opción interesante, es el paquete [`installr`](https://github.com/talgalili/installr/) que te ofrece instalar herramientas adicionales directamente desde la consola R.

#### Rlang

El problema básico, es que se necesita la versión de desarrollo de `rlang` y ésta es algo complicada de instalar. El tema es que para instalar versiones de desarrollo, usamos normalmente `devtools::install_github("nombre_paquete")`, pero el problema es que `devtools` necesita de `rlang`, por lo que no la podemos usar para instalarla. La alternativa es usar el paquete `remotes`, y seguir estos pasos:

- Reiniciar una sesión R completamente limpia
- Desinstalar `rlang` con: `remove.packages("rlang")`
- Instalar ahora sí: `remotes::install_github("r-lib/rlang")`

**Atención**: Si nunca has usado `remotes` es probable que la conexión con `guithub` no este autenticada, por lo que si intentas instalar en más de una oportunidad, es posible, que `github` te rechace por que superaste la cuota de descagas diarias. Si ocurre eso, `remotes` imprimirá por pantalla una ayuda que deberás seguir, básicamente: (a) generar un token en la página de github (b) incorporar este token al archivo `.Renviron`, (c) reiniciar R. Con esto ya no deberías tener problemas con las cuotas.

#### `tidyverse/tidyr`

Con `rlang v 0.3.4.9003` (al menos) instalado ya deberías poder instalar `tidyr`, te recomiendo de esta forma: `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr", force = TRUE)`. Posiblemente te advierta que falta actualizar algún paquete, por ejemplo `vctrs`, y te pregunte que hacer, actualiza todos los paquetes que sean necesarios.

Código para probar las funciones, finalmente:

```
mtcars %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "am", values_from = "mpg") 

# A tibble: 32 x 11
     cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs  gear  carb   `1`   `0`
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     4     4  21    NA  
 2     6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     4     4  21    NA  
 3     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     4     1  22.8  NA  
 4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     3     1  NA    21.4
 5     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     3     2  NA    18.7
 6     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     3     1  NA    18.1
 7     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     3     4  NA    14.3
 8     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     4     2  NA    24.4
 9     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     4     2  NA    22.8
10     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     4     4  NA    19.2
# ... with 22 more rows

relig_income %>%
  pivot_longer(-religion, names_to = "income", values_to = "count")

# A tibble: 180 x 3
   religion income             count
   <chr>    <chr>              <dbl>
 1 Agnostic <$10k                 27
 2 Agnostic $10-20k               34
 3 Agnostic $20-30k               60
 4 Agnostic $30-40k               81
 5 Agnostic $40-50k               76
 6 Agnostic $50-75k              137
 7 Agnostic $75-100k             122
 8 Agnostic $100-150k            109
 9 Agnostic >150k                 84
10 Agnostic Don't know/refused    96
# ... with 170 more rows
```

#### Comentario final

No está de más decir,que trabajar con versiones de desarrollo de cualquier paquete puede ser peligroso, y con paquetes tan básicos como `rlang` o incluso `tidyr` lo es mucho más, 
no es recomendable hacerlo en un entorno productivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, Patricio. Lamentablemente no pude conseguirlo, repetiré los pasos una vez más esperando que funcione. Muchisimas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Hola Jonathan, agrega a tu pregunta cualquier dato adicional y sobre todo cualquier mensaje de error que te estuviera dando, con gusto lo miro. Te cuento que el procedimiento que te pasé me funcionó finalmente en un Windows 10. Suerte.